# Ruby: pushing element on array inside a Hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

From an input file with many lines of 'name=value' fields looking like (top 20 lines)

```
Job=C201A005 include=PC201
Job=C201A005 proc=RUNTRACN
Job=C201A005 proc=RUNTRACN utilpgm=IEFBR14
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005 utilpgm=SORT
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005 include=SORT
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005 file=PC201.AD.SRVCPT.INPUT
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005 pdsmem=ULDH.REHOST3.PARM/SA005
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005 include=BATC2P
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005 include=BATC2P file=ULDH.REHOST3.LOADBTCH
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005 include=BATC2P file=SYS2.DB2DBP1.SDSNLOAD
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005 include=BATC2P file=SYS2.DB2DBP1.RUNLIB.LOAD
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005 include=BATC2P file=SYS2.S99I0062.PROD.SCSQLOAD
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005 include=BATC2P file=ULDH.REHOST3.REXX
Job=C201A005 proc=DD0005 include=BATC2P file=ULDH.REHOST3.REXX
Job=C201A005 proc=ABENDJOB
Job=C201A005 proc=ABENDJOB utilpgm=IEFBR14
Job=C201A005 proc=ABENDJOB file=PROD.NET.MSGS
Job=C201A018 include=PC201
Job=C201A018 proc=RUNTRACN
```

I'm trying to build a data structure to hold 'for each "Job" a structure of arrays of each type (proc, include,file, program, utilpgm..)'
Here is the code I wrote. I'm unable to push a 'value' on the appropriate array.

```
 #!/usr/bin/ruby

jobs={} #holds everything
currentjob=""
files=[], pdsmems=[], includs=[], procs=[], programs=[], utilpgms=[]

ARGF.each do |line|
    # chop the line into fields,
    # where every field is a 'name=value' pair.
    line.chomp!
    fields = line.split(' ')

    print "Currentjob = >#{currentjob}<\n"

    for field in fields do
        fieldname, value = field.split('=')        # split into name, value
        #print ">> #{fieldname}=#{value}\n"
        if fieldname =~ /[jJ]ob/
            if currentjob != value
                print "NEW JOB #{fields[0].split('=')[1]}\n"
                # this is a new job, so build the hash for old one
                files=[], pdsmems=[], includs=[], procs=[], programs=[], utilpgms=[]
                jobelements = {'file' => files, 'pdsmem' => pdsmems,
                               'include' => includs, 'proc' => procs,
                               'program' => programs, 'utilpgm' => utilpgms}
                jobs[value] = jobelements
                #print "Hash assigned. job = #{jobs} \n"
                currentjob = value
            end
            next
        end
        print "fieldname = #{fieldname}\n"

        # push 'value' on the appro. array in the 'jobelements' hash
        # which is value of the 'currentjob' key.
        #jobs[currentjob][fieldname].push(value)   # <== HELP!
        #jobs[currentjob][fieldname] << value      # <== HELP!

    end
end

 #print the data structure
print jobs
```

I can't seem to get the syntax right to reference the correct array and push an elemnt onto it. 
Help appreciated.
Cheers!
P.S.

The expected output is like below:

```
["C201A005", {"file"=>["PC201.AD.SRVCPT.INPUT", "ULDH.REHOST3.LOADBTCH", "SYS2.DB2DBP1.SDSNLOAD", "SYS2.DB2DBP1.RUNLIB.LOAD", "SYS2.S99I0062.PROD.SCSQLOAD", "ULDH.REHOST3.REXX", "PROD.NET.MSGS"], "pdsmem"=>["ULDH.REHOST3.PARM/SA005"], "include"=>["PC201", "SORT", "BATC2P"], "proc"=>["RUNTRACN", "DD0005", "ABENDJOB"], "program"=>[], "utilpgm"=>["IEFBR14", "SORT"]}]

["C201A018", {"file"=>[], "pdsmem"=>[], "include"=>["PC201"], "proc"=>["RUNTRACN"], "program"=>[], "utilpgm"=>[]}]
```

Comment: You should post the expected result rather than your code to make your intent clear. Reading through a code written by a beginner is a pain. And you probably do not need to show twenty lines. Create a minimal example that shows your point.

Comment: We need to see the code. While it's sometimes a pain, it's also an opportunity to help them learn how to write it better, in addition to fixing the problem. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance." Showing us what output you expect is essential in any question like this.

Comment: I pasted the entire code so if someone wants to run it on their setup can do so (and added some input as well).

Comment: Well, apologies for being unclear earlier (and a little late now), I used to get runtime error earlier when I tried to push a value onto an array "..no such method "<<" on Nilclass:.." or "no such methos "push" on ..". See lines marked with "HELP!" in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you initialize your array variables probably does not work the way you want it to.

```
files=[], pdsmems=[], includs=[], procs=[], programs=[], utilpgms=[]
```

does not create a new empty array called files, but files will look like this:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

this is because `,` is not the end of a statement, but will create an array off all the other values following and preceding it.

Example:

```
a = [1], b = [2], c = [3]
puts a.to_s # returns '[[1], [2], [3]]' and not '[1]'
```

You can fix this through replacing your `,` with `;` or a new line. `;` terminates a statement and acts like a line break;

For an easy way to test short ruby snippets have a look at [pry](http://pryrepl.org/) or irb (probably already installed with ruby).

Comment: But, we very seldom use `;` to separate statements when writing Ruby. It's idiomatic to put them on separate lines.

Comment: Using ';' instead of '.' did it. A few more tweaks and my goal is achieved. Many thanks. Do you see a more elegant way to accomplish this whole thing?

Comment: @yogmk Sorry, I don't know of a simpler way to do this. Although it seems like something a gem might exist to simplify this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basics how to create arrays and hashes:

```
#create empty array called jobs
jobs = []
#or use jobs = Array.new
#create a hash  from one of your lines:
line = {"Job" => "C201A018", "proc" => "RUNTRACN" }
#add the line to your jobs
jobs.push(line)
#or do it this way:
#jobs << line
```

Comment: Better practice would be use of JSON-style hash in Ruby: `{Job: "C201A018", proc: "RUNTRACN"}`

Comment: "JSON-style" results in symbols, not strings, for the keys. That might be useful, or it might get in the way, only the OP knows for sure. Using symbols is certainly common and has some benefits, but how the hash will be used determines the best practice in the long-run.